# forwarding every request(other than specified) to same php file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to route every request(with params) to file home.php without changing the URL other than few we would like to go as normal i.e.

/user.php?a=new  should forward to /home.php?a=new but browser url still should show /user.php?a=new

/profiles/user.php?a=delete should point to /home.php?a=delete and url should stay same as entered.

and not forward for this url
/bounce/setting.php should still go to /bounce/setting.php. basically anything under /bounce should work as usual.

Thanks in advance.

Vishal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !bounce/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /home.php [L,QSA]
```

... assuming the user.php etc. scripts don't really exist.

Comment: Might wanna fix up the RewriteCOnd to be RewriteCond. +1 anyway!

Comment: Thanks. much appreciated. Let me try this and report back.